# How can I plot a 2 dimensional random walk in python?

Tags: python, random-walk

I wrote the code for a two dimensional random walk:

```
def r2walk(T):
    x = np.zeros((T))
    y = np.zeros((T))
    x = [0]*T
    y = [0]*T
    for t in range(0,T):
        walk = random.random()
        if 0 < walk < .25:
            x[t] = x[t-1] + 1
        elif .25 < walk < .5:
            x[t] = x[t-1] - 1
        elif .5 < walk < 0.75:
            y[t] = y[t-1] + 1
        else:
            y[t] = y[t-1] - 1
     return x, y
```

I would like to be able to plot the path of the random walk on a x,y grid but am unsure how to proceed. Also I am very new to python and I would appreciate any tips on writing code more efficiently (or elegantly as your perspective might put it). Thank you in advance!

Comment: x = [0]*T : this makes the previous definition of x get forgotten, and is completely unnecessary. To plot, just use plot() from matplotlib.

Comment: You might also consider doing `for t in range(1,T):`, because now on round 0 you probably accidentally use the item `x[-1]` (which is zero and does not cause any severe damage in this context). There are also some rather simple ways of creating your walk by using `np.cumsum`, but that is another story. (The friendly people at CodeReview might want to help you to iron out the small inefficiencies if you want faster and more compact code.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some plotting package. The most commonly used is `matplotlib` which works splendidly with `numpy`.

Then your code looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

def r2walk(T):
    x = np.zeros((T))
    y = np.zeros((T))
    for t in range(0,T):
        walk = random.random()
        if 0 < walk < .25:
            x[t] = x[t-1] + 1
        elif .25 < walk < .5:
            x[t] = x[t-1] - 1
        elif .5 < walk < 0.75:
            y[t] = y[t-1] + 1
        else:
            y[t] = y[t-1] - 1
    return x, y



x, y = r2walk(100)

# create a figure
fig = plt.figure()
# create a plot into the figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# plot the data
ax.plot(x,y)
```

This will give you:

[image]

If you are completely new with `matplotlib`, I suggest you have a look at `IPython` and `pylab` plus of course some `matplotlib` tutorials. You can plot your walk in a million different ways.